# What is the workaround for WMI remote connection failure with Access Denied error when client runs with Local System account?

Tags: windows, security, networking, wmi

What is the workaround for WMI remote connection failure with Access Denied error when client runs with Local System account?

I tried to run script under local system account on the client which connects to remote WMI (namespace: root\cimv2) using local administrator credentials of remote machine. But WMI connection failed with the following error. The remote server has firewall enabled and client has firewall disabled. Both client and remote server has windows 2012 R2 OS.

Access is denied.

Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x80070005: "Access is denied"

What could be the reason for this error? The same script worked when ran from another client machine.